# how to save javascript values to use in server code?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a label that shows the price depend on 2 other DropDownLists via javascript. I want to use this label value in my server code when submit button in hitted. how can I figure it out?

.aspx.cs page code:

```
  protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Int64 totalPrice = Convert.ToInt64(lblMablaghGhabelePardakht.Text);
       System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(totalPrice.ToString());
       return;
    }
```

.aspx page code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ratesArray = [[0, 0], [1, 1000], [2, 1500], [3, 2000], [4, 2500], [5, 3000]];
    var days = 7;
    var pricePerDay = 0;
    var TotalPrice;

    function timleLimitDrpFunc() {
        var tElem = document.getElementById('<%=drpTimeLimit.ClientID%>');
        days = tElem.options[tElem.selectedIndex].value;
        TotalPrice = days * pricePerDay;
        SetPrice();
    }

    function ratesDrpFunc() {
        var rElem = document.getElementById('<%=drpRates.ClientID%>');
        var rateIndex = rElem.options[rElem.selectedIndex].value;
        pricePerDay = ratesArray[rateIndex][1];
        TotalPrice = days * pricePerDay;
        SetPrice();
    }    

    function SetPrice() {
        var pElem = document.getElementById('<%=lblMablaghGhabelePardakht.ClientID%>');
        pElem.innerHTML = TotalPrice; 
        pElem.value = TotalPrice;   
    }                   
</script>
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpRates" runat="server" onchange="ratesDrpFunc(); return false;">
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="drpTimeLimit" runat="server" onchange="timleLimitDrpFunc(); return false;">
</asp:DropDownList>

 <asp:Label ID="lblMablaghGhabelePardakht" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label>
<span>ریال</span>

<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="ثبت" class="FormButton" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"
    ValidationGroup="submit" />
```

---

**Changes after comments:**
I maked below changes but returns null(0)... where is my problem?!

```
function SetPrice() {
   var pElem = document.getElementById('<%=lblMablaghGhabelePardakht.ClientID%>');
   pElem.innerHTML = TotalPrice;
   pElem.value = TotalPrice;

   var hElem = document.getElementById('<%=hndTotalPrice.ClientID%>');
   hElem.valu = TotalPrice;                
   }                                        
   </script>
   <asp:HiddenField ID="hndTotalPrice" runat="server" />
```

.

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strtest = hndTotalPrice.Value;    
       // Int64 totalPrice = Convert.ToInt64(lblMablaghGhabelePardakht.Text);
        Int64 totalPrice = Convert.ToInt64(hndTotalPrice.Value);
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(totalPrice.ToString());
        return;
    }
```

---

**Answer:**
I used 
 `hElem.setAttribute("value", TotalPrice);` 
instead of 
`hElem.valu = TotalPrice;` 
and my problem resolved.

Comment: Not sure how it translates into asp.net, the usual method (language agnostic) would be either Ajax or setting the value in a hidden field.

Comment: `Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show` in ASP.NET code?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter It's just used to test the result... my page is a bit complicated that I cant see the result of response.write()...

Comment: @SJuan76 How can I use a hidden field?

Comment: Just a hint, instead of using `MessageBox.Show` for outputting diagnostics, use `Debug.WriteLine` with a debugger attached - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

From @SJuan76's comment on the hidden field & your question on how to use it:

`<asp:HiddenField ID='someID' runat='server' />`

Then use javascript to set the value once you know the final price. You'll need to use the client id in the javascript.

Here is an article on that: http://www.jagregory.com/writings/how-to-use-clientids-in-javascript-without-the-ugliness/

---

change your `SetPrice` function to this and see if that will fix the problem, and here 'TotalPrice' should be the parameter.

```
function SetPrice(TotalPrice) {
   var pElem = document.getElementById('<%= lblMablaghGhabelePardakht.ClientID %>');
   pElem.innerHTML = TotalPrice;
   pElem.value = TotalPrice;

   var hElem = document.getElementById('<%= hndTotalPrice.ClientID %>');
   hElem.valu = TotalPrice;                
}
```

You don't declare the `TotalPrice` in the set price function so it doesn't know what that is. So it could return null/0 based upon that.

Comment: The link is not about hidden fields!

Comment: No, it's not. It's about using the client id's in javascript. It's not hard to replace an asp text box with a hidden field. Same basic principle... Once you set the value using javascript and go to server side code you can access the hidden field value with the hidden field's id.

Comment: thx a lot for your link... I read it 3 times... but I didn't get how to solve my problem again :( ... would you plz write the code here? (I updated my question)

Comment: I added  `console.log('hnd amount:' + hElem.valu);` to the end of this function... It shows the right value in client side... but it is null in server side...